# Best Customize Listing Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have a web-site with 20 pages.

i want to display a page with list of new pages links like A-Z other than the above 20 pages.

Can someone suggest a best plugin to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these plugins: [Page List](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-list/) or [List Pages Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-pages-shortcode/)

Comment: The above plugins doesn't have a good documentation and finds hard to use it. Do you suggest anything else?????

Comment: They have enough documentation for their plugin. They are very small plugin with some Shortcode. You will find some shortcode in plugins page. Just install the plugin and use shortcode wherever you want.